# Set orientation when picking a file from gallery

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

Currently I'm picking a file (Video) from the Gallery by doing:

```
private void selectVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
}
```

The above will open the Gallery and let the user select a file, this works perfect.

---

**My question:**

Is there a way to set a fixed orientation of the Gallery when the user selects a file? I can't find any information about this, is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "set a fixed orientation of the Gallery when the user selects a file"? Do you mean something like "force the activity that I am starting to be in landscape, even though the device may be in portrait"?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do, my application is in portrait mode and if the device is in landscape mode and the user selects a file the gallery rotates, instead I want the gallery to stay in portrait mode.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. After all, you have no way of knowing if that other activity *supports* portrait mode.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please elaborate on "After all, you have no way of knowing if that other activity supports portrait mode" - it is android gallery and as far as I know android gallery supports landscape and portrait?

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models. Those models will ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of different "gallery" apps. Those models may ship with other apps that support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` of `video/*`. Users may install any of hundreds of additional apps (galleries, file managers, etc.) from the Play Store or elsewhere. None of those hundreds (perhaps thousands) of apps necessarily has to support all orientations, but your code could be starting activities from any of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I understand. So would your recommendation be to create my own activity and get the files from Gallery, set the orientation of that activity and use that as my file picker?

Comment: Assuming that by "get the files from Gallery", you mean "query the `MediaStore` for relevant content", you could do that. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` would allow the user to choose things that are not necessarily known to the `MediaStore` (e.g., content in Google Drive). Plus, writing your own picker-style UI is tedious, particularly for situations where you will want to show images (in your case, video thumbnails). You need to decide if controlling the orientation is important enough to be worth those limitations.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok thank you for you great pointers.